# Cofactor Matrices

Tags: code-golf, math, matrix, linear-algebra

The cofactor matrix is the transpose of the [Adjugate Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix). The elements of this matrix are the [cofactors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_%28linear_algebra%29) of the original matrix.

The cofactor [image] (i.e. the element of the cofactor matrix at row i and column j) is the determinant of the submatrix formed by deleting the ith row and jth column from the original matrix, multiplied by (-1)^(i+j).

For example, for the matrix

[image]

The element of the cofactor matrix at row 1 and column 2 is:

[image]

You can find info on what the determinant of a matrix is and how to calculate them [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant).

#### Challenge

Your goal is to output the cofactor matrix of an input matrix.

**Note**: Built-ins that evaluate cofactor matrices, or adjugate matrices, or determinants or anything similar are **allowed**.

#### Input

The matrix may be inputed as a command line argument, as a function parameter, in `STDIN` or in any way that is most appropriate for the language you use.

The matrix will be formatted as a list of lists, each sublist corresponding to one row, which contains factors ordered from left to right. Rows are ordered from top to bottom in the list.

For example, the matrix

```
a b
c d
```

will be represented by `[[a,b],[c,d]]`.

You may replace the square brackets and commas with something else if it fits your language and is sensible (e.g. `((a;b);(c;d))`)

Matrices will **only contain integers (which can be negative)**.

Matrices will **always be square** (i.e. same number of rows and columns).

You may assume that the input will always be correct (i.e. no formatting problem, nothing other than integers, no empty matrix).

#### Output

The resulting cofactor matrix may be outputed to `STDOUT`, returned from a function, written to a file, or anything similar that naturally suits the language you use.

The cofactor matrix must be formatted in the exact same way the input matrices are given, e.g. `[[d,-c],[-b,a]]`. If you read a string, then you must return/output a string in which the matrix is formatted exactly like in the input. If you use something like e.g. a list of lists as input, then you must return a list of lists too.

#### Test cases

- Input: `[[1]]`

Output: `[[1]]`

- Input: `[[1,2],[3,4]]`

Output: `[[4,-3],[-2,1]]`

- Input: `[[-3,2,-5],[-1,0,-2],[3,-4,1]]`

Output: `[[-8,-5,4],[18,12,-6],[-4,-1,2]]`

- Input: `[[3,-2,7,5,0],[1,-1,42,12,-10],[7,7,7,7,7],[1,2,3,4,5],[-3,14,-1,5,-9]]`

Output:

```
[[9044,-13580,-9709,23982,-9737],[-1981,1330,3689,-3444,406],[14727,7113,2715,-9792,414],[-28448,-2674,-707,16989,14840],[-2149,2569,-2380,5649,-3689]]
```

#### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret *the cofactor matrix must be formatted in the exact same way the input matrices are given* for function submissions that get input from arguments and return a value. Do we read/return actual matrices or their string representations?

Comment: In short: if you read a string, then you must return/output a string in which the matrix is formatted exactly like in the input. If you use something like e.g. a list of lists, then you must return a list of lists too.

Comment: Does a 1x1 matrix really have a cofactor matrix?

Comment: Also your penultimate test case seems to be the adjugate matrix (the transpose of what it should be), unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ICanHazHats Correct, I fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## J, 29 bytes

```
3 :'<.0.5+|:(-/ .**%.)1e_9+y'
```

Same epsilon/inverse/determinant trick. From right to left:

- `1e_9+` adds an epsilon,
- `(-/ .**%.)` is *determinant* (`-/ .*`) times *inverse* (`%.`),
- `|:` transposes,
- `<.0.5+` rounds.

Answer (score 5):

## Matlab, <s>42</s> 33 bytes

Using an anonymous function:

```
@(A)round(inv(A+eps)'*det(A+eps))
```

Input and output are matrices (2D numeric arrays).

`eps` is added in case the matrix is singular. It is "removed" using `round` (the true result is guaranteed to be an integer).

Example:

```
>> @(A)round(inv(A+eps)'*det(A+eps))
ans = 
    @(A)round(inv(A+eps)'*det(A+eps))
>> ans([-3,2,-5; -1,0,-2; 3,-4,1])
ans =
-8    -5     4
18    12    -6
-4    -1     2
```

Example with singular matrix:

```
>> @(A)round(inv(A+eps)'*det(A+eps))
ans = 
    @(A)round(inv(A+eps)*det(A+eps)')
>> ans([1,0 ; 0,0])
ans =
     0     0
     0     1
```

Or [try it online](http://ideone.com/NoIUmO) in Octave.

Comment: Matlab definitely feels like "the right tool for the job" in this challenge

Comment: Wait until someone posts a Mathematica answer... it probably has a builtin for this :-)

Comment: However I do have a concern that I haven't talked about in the challenge: this answer assumes that the input matrix is invertible. Using your code on say `[1,0 ; 0,0]` gives an error when it should output `[0,0 ; 0,1]`

Comment: Hm. You're right. I hadn't thought of that

Comment: Corrected! With a dirty trick, I admit

Comment: Since you are returning from a function, I don't think you should need `mat2str`: "resulting cofactor matrix may be... returned from a function"

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Thanks! But "_The cofactor matrix must be formatted in the exact same way the input matrices are given_". That's why I think I need `mat2str`

Comment: Can you explain a bit more to non-Matlab people like me what the `eps` and `fix` commands do? Sounds like you tell Matlab to add a small epsilon to the matrix and fix magically removes its effects afterwards, but is there a guarantee that it always yields exactly the correct cofactor matrix?

Comment: @Fatalize Yes, it's that. `eps` is about 1e-16. So it makes the matrix non-singular (but very ill-conditioned). The result is not exactly integer; so `fix` (round towards zero) fixes that. This works provided the error doesn't exceed `.5`. I'm afraid there are no guarantees. For very large integers it might fail. I said it was a _dirty_ trick :-P

Comment: @Fatalize for clarity, could you say whether `mat2str` is needed here? To me it feels like since this is a function, the input actually is the unformatted matrix. Like if you try `f=...` then do `f(f(...))` this won't work, but removing `mat2str` makes that work fine.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Now I see what you mean. Yes, without `mat2str`, the function output could be used as a new input. Let's wait for @Fatalize's clarification

Comment: WHY NOT MATL??? PS: The `'` is in the wrong position, I think.

Comment: @flawr I didn't include much of linear algebra in MATL :-) Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, <s>27</s> 35 bytes

```
Thread[Det[#+x]Inverse[#+x]]/.x->0&
```

Comment: Does this work for non-invertible matrices, e.g. `[[1,0],[0,0]]`?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman That doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3):

## R, <s>121</s> 94 bytes

```r
function(A)t(outer(1:(n=NROW(A)),1:n,Vectorize(function(i,j)(-1)^(i+j)*det(A[-i,-j,drop=F]))))
```

This is an absurdly long function that accepts an object of class `matrix` and returns another such object. To call it, assign it to a variable.

Ungolfed:

```r
cofactor <- function(A) {
    # Get the number of rows (and columns, since A is guaranteed to
    # be square) of the input matrix A
    n <- NROW(A)

    # Define a function that accepts two indices i,j and returns the
    # i,j cofactor
    C <- function(i, j) {
        # Since R loves to drop things into lower dimensions whenever
        # possible, ensure that the minor obtained by column deletion
        # is still a matrix object by adding the drop = FALSE option
        a <- A[-i, -j, drop = FALSE]

        (-1)^(i+j) * det(a)
    }

    # Obtain the adjugate matrix by vectorizing the function C over
    # the indices of A
    adj <- outer(1:n, 1:n, Vectorize(C))

    # Transpose to obtain the cofactor matrix
    t(adj)
}
```

Comment: [80 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/P600L7kkMz9Pw1ezRCM3saAgp1IDLpapk6WpoWuoGaeRqZ2lqZWSWqLhG62bqaObpZNSlF9g6xarqVOUXw7Uq5OcnwOkNDX//wcA "R – Try It Online") using `mapply` instead of `outer` and `Vectorize`

Answer (score 2):

## [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org), 246 Bytes

You can tell this is good coding by the triple nested for-loops.

It's pretty straightforward. GAP doesn't really have the same tools to deal with matrices that other math oriented languages do. The only thing really used here is the built in determinant operator.

```
f:=function(M)local A,B,i,j,v;A:=StructuralCopy(M);if not Size(M)=1 then for i in [1..Size(M)] do for j in [1..Size(M)] do B:=StructuralCopy(M);for v in B do Remove(v,j);od;Remove(B,i);A[i][j]:= (-1)^(i+j)*DeterminantMat(B);od;od;fi;Print(A);end;
```

ungolfed:

```
f:=function(M)
    local A,B,i,j,v;
    A:=StructuralCopy(M);
    if not Size(M)=1 then
        for i in [1..Size(M)] do
            for j in [1..Size(M)] do
                B:=StructuralCopy(M);
                for v in B do
                    Remove(v,j);
                od;
                Remove(B,i);
                 A[i][j]:= (-1)^(i+j)*DeterminantMat(B);
            od;
        od;
    fi;
    Print(A);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Verbosity v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Verbosity-v2), 196 bytes

```
IncludeTypePackage<Matrix>
IncludeTypePackage<OutputSystem>
print=OutputSystem:NewOutput<DEFAULT>
input=Matrix:Adjugate<ARGV0>
input=Matrix:Transpose<input>
OutputSystem:DisplayAsText<print;input>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY3LDoIwFET3/QqWsFN0haVJE9SY@IpW9xVuSBVL04fSr68GNmpcnpnJmQfoS2uE9WkIK1k2rgLmFex5eeM14A23WnQE/al2zipnj95YuBOktJA2/8yyLTwHxsV8QU9rRpCQb8wHaUarq6u5BUwPy/Pop2SaS6NaA7iPCfpSF8KohntqGHQW99@zYRdCiONxlCZRPImmSfIC)

<sub>NB: Doesn't currently work on TIO, awaiting a pull. Should work offline</sub>

Takes input in the form `((a b)(c d))` to represent

$$
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
a \: b \\
c \: d
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$$

Despite having a builtin for the adjugate, Verbosity's verbosity still cripples it. Fairly basic how it works, just transposes the adjugate of the input.